# Как правильно использовать опцию --protocol для сервера xsp в mono?

Tags: mono

Запускаю сервер xsp из mono вот такой командой:

```
"%programfiles%\Mono-2.10.9\bin\xsp"  --https-client-accept --port 443 --root "путь к сайту" --p12file "путь к p12 файлу" --pkpwd "пароль" --protocol Tls
```

А он не стартует, а показывает только параметры использования. Если же убрать опцию `--protocol`, то сервер стартует.

Answer (score 1):

Для Tls, как в вашем случае, прописывать протокол не нужно, т.к. в [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xsp.1.html) написано:

`-- protocol PROTOCOL
Specifies which  protocols  are  available  for  encrypting  the communications.   The possible values are Default, Tls and Ssl3. Ssl2 isn't supported.  The  default  value  is  "Default"  which auto-detect  the  client protocol and adjust the server protocol accordingly.`

Параметры протокола, Tls или Ssl3 определяются автоматически, если не были заданы вручную. По поводу вашей ошибки: возможно стоит заключить слово Tls в кавычки?